# AMP Story being marked as noindex on Google AMP Validation, but there is no noindex tag inside the AMP Story

Tags: seo, amp-html, google-search, amp-story, amp-stories

I have an AMP story page that even if the AMP Validator passes it as valid, the Google AMP Test prompts me that it is invalid with a Indexing error that says `URL marked 'noindex'`.

Obviously i do not have any noindex meta on the content of the page and i do not know why the Google AMP Test does not validate the story.

Any clues would be appreciated!

[AMP story page](https://storypal.net/story/dnaviruses)

[AMP Validator Test](https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fstorypal.net%2Fstory%2Fdnaviruses)

[Google AMP Test](https://search.google.com/test/amp?utm_source=gws&utm_medium=onebox&utm_campaign=suit&id=QTj0q-Sy_h0ZEmpfttpnUg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not caused by the contents of your page but rather the HTTP headers.  The headers of this page are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Date => Wed, 05 Feb 2020 16:39:25 GMT
Server => Apache
Cache-Control => max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
pragma => no-cache
expires => -1
X-Robots-Tag => noindex
Access-Control-Allow-Origin => *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers => authorization, origin, user-token, x-requested-with, content-type, Content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods => PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Connection => close
Content-Type => text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The `X-Robots-Tag => noindex` causes Google's AMP Test service to not be able to fetch your page to evaluate whether it is valid.  Removing this header should resolve the issue.

Comment: `X-Robots-Tag => noindex` is changed through cPanel? Should i create a robots.txt? why is by default on noindex?

Comment: This is all going to be completely dependent on your hosting environment and tech stack, so unfortunately there's no generic answer that can be useful here.  But, you can likely check with your webhost to find out.